# Tslint: simple syntax check

Tags: typescript, tslint

How can I use tslint to do a simple syntax check of my project ?
At the moment, I don't want to enforce other style/code rules.
My tslint.json is:

```
{
    "defaultSeverity": "error",
    "extends": [
        "tslint:recommended"
    ],
    "jsRules": {},
    "rules": {},
    "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

Comment: but tslint is meant to do style checks.. syntax is checked already by the compiler..

Comment: I don't want a full compilation because the referred types are not reachable at that build step (they are in a different module to which the generated sources are added later).

Answer (score 0):

To run linting separately from other build steps, I typically add a `lint` script to `package.json`, like so:

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\tslint src\\**\\*.ts**"
  }
```

Then `yarn lint` or `npm run lint` to run the linter.